# Time not showing in the Crystal Report VB2015

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a strange problem with Crystal Report in Visual studio 2015. I am trying to create a report with the time of recording the operation

I used to store time in the nvarchar field

But after that I needed to do research between two times

So when I create a new table and make a time field I don't see the field in Crystal Report

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you updated the Data Source of the report? Sometimes even if you change the Table, if you don't update this source on the report those new fields won't show.

Comment: Make an update, make a new report, and create a new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must Use Anther library To connection db